# Azure Data Factory Missing Blob Triggers

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-trigger

I have created an ADF pipeline that should trigger when a blob is added to a storage container (say container1) and copy the blob to another storage container (say container2). All my blob names are alphanumeric with '-' (basically a GUID). I see that the ADF is triggered only a few times  compared to the number of blobs in container1 (i.e if I have n files in container1, the ADF is triggered only x times where x<n).

I also observed that whenever the blobs created per second in container1 is high there are more missed triggers. I am not using any event batching in the event grid. My storage account is v2 BlockBlobStorage.

Is there a way I can resolve this?

Comment: Have you filtered certain file types, so the number of triggers is less?

Comment: My blob trigger is only for blob created not blob deleted. But no blobs are deleted though. All the triggers are for created only

Comment: Hi @Sankar Mantripragada,I've created several tests but unfortunately I couldn't reproduce your issues. Can you tell us any progress now?

Comment: Sometimes my storage can have around 100,000 blobs per hour, the triggers are missing if the inflow is that high.

Comment: Update: I changed the design not to use trigger pattern, instead kept a timer trigger to process blobs every hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#polling-and-latency) they mentioned "There's no guarantee that all events are captured."

Answer (score 0):

I think it is difficult for us to get the correct answer in the community. We'd better move this issue to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/index.html). After MS's stress test to find out the possibility of bugs.